# Phpmyadmin 5.0.2 error when cloning database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I apologize in advance for my English, I have updated both mysql (5.7.30) and Phpmyadmin (5.0.2). It happens that when copying a database with a different name, the views in the clause where you are adding something like databasename.tablename, in previous versions did not someone know why this happens?

In the previous version when cloning a database (Enterprise) with a different name (NewEnterprise) the views kept their original structure, example:

```
CREATE VIEW customerPayments
AS 
select ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME 
from customer;
```

In the current version, when it is cloned, the structures change, being in the new database, the views refer to the previous example:

```
CREATE VIEW customerPayments
AS 
select ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME 
from Enterprise.custome
```

Where should something like

```
CREATE VIEW customerPayments
AS 
select ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME 
from NewEnterprise.custome
```

Or as it happened that left it without the alias of the database.
I hope I have made myself understood, otherwise please let me know and I will try to expand the information

Comment: Your english is fine. No-one should ever have to apologize for it. I see you are exhibiting a different behavior that wasn't there in previously (phpmyadmin?).  Your title mentions an error but you haven't told is what the error is. Start simple, what do you see? What do you expect to see? Edit question to include the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a side-effect of how MySQL handles views — they are strictly defined with the database, table, and column names all needing to be explicitly referenced in the view (for instance, a view of `` SELECT * FROM `bar`; `` gets interpreted and stored as `` SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `foo`.`bar`; ``. So even though you may not have explicitly set the database name or even column names in the view, that's how MySQL stores them.

When copying a database, phpMyAdmin should do the helpful thing and ask you to adjust these; it doesn't right now. I've added a feature request at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16214 to add that functionality.